# Scanner with a lookbehind delimiter does not work near Scanner.BUFFER_SIZE boundary

Tags: java, regex-lookarounds

If I use a `Scanner` with a delimiter that contains a lookbehind, like `(?<=de)lim`, the delimiter is not skipped when I design my input such that the internal buffer of the Scanner starts with `"lim"`, even though in the source text it is preceded by `"de"`:

```java
public class Scanning {
    final static int SCANNER_BUFFER_SIZE = 1024 * 2;
    final static int OFFSET = 5;
    final static String DATA = "=".repeat(SCANNER_BUFFER_SIZE - OFFSET) + "delimdelim" + "=".repeat(10);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new StringReader(DATA));

        scanner.useDelimiter("(?<=de)lim");

        while(scanner.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(scanner.next().replaceAll("=+", "="));
        }
    }
}
```

I think that `DATA` should be split on these delimiters:

```
===(...)===delimdelim==========
             ^~~  ^~~
```

And so the output should be:

```
=de
de
=
```

However, this outputs (openjdk version "17.0.2" 2022-01-18):

```
=de
limde
=
```

I can see in the debugger that when the scanner is about to return `"limde"`, `scanner.buf` and `scanner.matcher.text` contain `"limdelim..."`, so I suspect that it the cause. If I alter `OFFSET` to e.g. `3` or `7`, my expected behavior occurs.

I could not find any reference to this behavior in the documentation of `Scanner` or `Pattern`, so is this intended? Is it not safe to use lookaround for the delimiter of a `Scanner`?

Comment: You may simply split your string with the pattern, `DATA.split("(?<=de)lim")`. See https://ideone.com/aZDakN

Comment: I am aware you can achieve a similar result in other ways, my question is specifically about `Scanner`

Comment: I think this is a different version of this JDK bug: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8176407